# Google Map activity in android methods

Tags: google-maps, android-studio

what does these methods Means in android studio in  google map
1).**OnMapReadyCallback**
2). **LocationListener**
3). **GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks**
4). **GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener**

Comment: You should check [https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intro](Google Maps Android API) and [Google Maps Events Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/events).

Answer (score 0):

from [Android Developer docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/packages):

> **LocationListener**
> public interface LocationListener 
> android.location.LocationListener
>
> Used for receiving notifications from the LocationManager when the location has changed

it is just like using OnClickListener to detect a user's click, but it listens for changes in location. you can use it to perform a set of instruction when the user have localisation enabled and moves to another location.

---

**GoogleApiClient** is The main entry point for Google Play services integration, is what you use to connect the client (user, to the google play services

---

> **GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener**
>  public static interface
> GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
>  Provides callbacks for
> scenarios that result in a failed attempt to connect the client to the
> service.

it is used to define what should happen (just a set of instructions), in case your attempt to connect to the google play services has failed

---

> **GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks**
>  public static interface GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks
>  Provides callbacks that are
> called when the client is connected or disconnected from the service

this is very similar to the previous one, but instead of defining what should be done when a the client fails to connect, it defines what should be done, when a connection to the google play services is successfully established, or if a disconnection with the services has been preformed.

---

as for the rest :
i got this information from the documentation,
i invite you to read it before posting, it contains all the information that you may need, and try to implement the methods your self to understand how they work